# Checking if path is under a folder name using PathAndQuery

Tags: c#

I am using c# to check to see if the url page is under a folder/file name but does not seem to work. I am not sure why the PathAndQuery does not work. If my path is
        https://www.xyz.com/VAR/Default.aspx

I am not sure why it does not make it inside of the below else if statement:

```
        else if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("~/VAF/Default.aspx") > 0)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Please explain what “does not work” means. What do you expect to happen? What happens? Why do you think the two are different?

Comment: @DourHighArch - Ok - I put more of an explanation..

Answer (score 1):

https://www.xyz.com

/VAR/Default.aspx

~/VAF/Default.aspx

See the difference? Is this a typo in your code? Should it instead be:

```
 else if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("~/VAF/Default.aspx") > 0)
        {

        }
```